# How to update a recyclerview when new data sa been added in Sqlite database

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

It has been 2 days and I still can't figure out why can't my `RecyclerView` update immediately when I insert a data in `sqlite` database.

I been trying many methods such `nofityDataSetChanged` and `swapAdapter` but still my `RecyclerView` won't update, to update it I need to go to another activity before the data has been added into the `RecyclerView`.

So can anyone tell me where am i doing it wrong?

**Heres my code for query**

```
public void AddData(){
    reg_pet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            items=new ArrayList<>();
            final int position=0;
            adapter=new reg_Adapter(getActivity(),items);
            boolean insterdata = myDB.insertDataToPetRegister(pet_name.getText().toString(),
                    spin_type.getSelectedItem().toString(), spin_breed.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    if (insterdata = true) {
                        adapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        pet_name.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Pet has been Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Pet has not been Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }
    });
}
```

**My Adapter**

```
public class reg_Adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<reg_ViewHolder> {
Activity activity;
Register_pet_database register_pet_database;
List<db_getItem> items;
db_getItem adapter;
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
public reg_Adapter(Activity activity, List<db_getItem> items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
}

public reg_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.reg_pet_recycler, parent, false);
    return new reg_ViewHolder(view);
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(reg_ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.pet_name.setText(items.get(position).getPet_name());
    holder.pet_type.setText(items.get(position).getPet_type());
    holder.pet_breed.setText(items.get(position).getPet_breed());
    holder.btndel.setTag(items.get(position).getPet_name());
    holder.btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            register_pet_database=new Register_pet_database(v.getContext());
            Integer deleted =register_pet_database.deleteData(v.getTag().toString());
            if (deleted > 0) {
                items.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pet Has been Remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Pet not Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

}

**My code in my fragment**

```
public class pet_tab extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Register_pet_database register_pet_database;
ArrayList<db_getItem> arrayList;
reg_Adapter  reg_adapter;
db_getItem item;
ImageButton btndel;
TextView pet_name;
    Cursor c;
    public pet_tab() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pet_tab, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.reg_pet_recycler);
        btndel=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btndel);
        loadDb();
        return view;
    }
    public void loadDb(){
        register_pet_database=new Register_pet_database(getActivity());
        DBAdapter db=new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        db.openDB();
        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        c=register_pet_database.queryData("select * from Pet_Registered");
        final int position=0;
        try {
         if(c!=null){
             if(c.moveToFirst()){
                 do {
                     db_getItem item = new db_getItem();
                     item.setPet_name(c.getString(1));
                     item.setPet_type(c.getString(2));
                     item.setPet_breed(c.getString(3));
                     arrayList.add(item);

                 }while(c.moveToNext());
             }
         }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        reg_Adapter adapter=new reg_Adapter(getActivity(),arrayList);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);;
        recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapter,false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do both `notifyItemInserted` and `notifyDataSetChanged`, only the former, as long as you have the position correct. But **all that notify methods do is refresh the view**. You have to also make sure the actual dataset has been updated.

Your code is card to read and follow because of the php code style so I haven't updated your original sample but basically:

**In your Context:**

```
Pet myPet = new Pet(...);
boolean isSuccessful = db.insert(myPet.getName(), ..., ...);
if (isSuccessful) {
    mAdapter.add(myPet);
}
```

**In the adapter:**

```
public void add(Pet pet) {
    mData.insert(0, pet);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

As a general rule, [restrict responsibility](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074). If you find yourself having to manually track things like positions and calls to notify methods from outside of their owner (in this case adapter), then something is wrong.

Another option is to rely on a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) to automatically monitor changes

Answer (score 0):

Check out Android Jetpack's Room Persistence Library and Paging Library.

The **[Room Persistence Library](http://%20https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)**
provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow for more robust database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.

The library helps you create a cache of your app's data on a device that's running your app. This cache, which serves as your app's single source of truth, allows users to view a consistent copy of key information within your app, regardless of whether users have an internet connection.

The **[Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/#support-different-data-arch)**
helps you load and display small chunks of data at a time. Loading partial data on demand reduces usage of network bandwidth and system resources.
The library supports the following data architectures:

- Served only from a backend server.
- Stored only in an on-device database.
- A combination of the other sources, using the on-device database as a cache.